# Do Fireplaces and Cooking Hearths count as a Bake Bread Action Space?

Tags: agricola

Does the Fireplaces and Cooking Hearths count as a Bake Bread Action space? Can I put a worker on those cards to bake bread or can I only bake bread using the respective action space on the main board?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During the `Work Phase` your family members perform `Actions` that are selected from those currently available on the board.

Stage 1 has the `Sow and/or Bake Bread` Action which will show up sometime during the first four rounds (Other bake actions are also available depending on how many players there are). To use the Bake Bread part of this action you must have an `Improvement` that bakes the Bread like the `Fireplace`, `Cooking Hearth` or an `Oven`.

These Improvements are **not** Action Spaces themselves, they are just the tools you will use to make your Actions more efficient. You will put your worker on the Action space that bakes bread, then use an improvement to determine the outcome of the baking action. You may use every baking improvement you have as many times as it allows per Bake Bread action.

Note that the fireplaces and hearths can convert multiple grain while the ovens are limited to 1 or 2. The Clay Oven and Stone Oven, and some others like the Baker's Oven, allow you to Bake Bread immediately when they are purchased. Some Improvements, like the Windmill, allow you to convert grain to (more than one) food at any time without using a Bake action.